# Prolog: sum of elements of two lists compared to elements in third list

Tags: list, prolog

I am given 3 lists. The first two lists' number of elements are added up and compared to the third list, `compare(List1,List2,List3)`. The sum of the first two lists is checked to see if the total number of elements is less than or equal to the number of elements in the third list. This is what I currently have. I am getting an error with `Total is Total+1`.

```
lessThanEq(List1, List2, List3) :-
   T1 is 0,
   T2 is 0,
   T3 is 0, 
   addUp(List1, T1),
   addUp(List2, T2),
   addUp(List3, T3),
   T1 is T1+T2,
   T1 =< T3.

addUp([Head|Tail], Total) :-
   addUp(Tail, Total1),
   Total is Total1+1.
```

This is what I have so far.

Comment: You cannot reassign a variable value within a predicate clause. So `T1 is T1 + T2` will always fail (`T1` cannot be itself plus something the value of `T2`) unless the value of `T2` happens to be zero.

Answer (score 0):

You have some errors in your program:

First:
Remove instantiation of Tx variables to zero `T1 is 0, T2 is 0, T3 is 0`, you don't need to initialize this variable, also you should not instantiate the same variable in more than one condition in the same rule. The results may not be the expected.

Second:
Use a different variable to instantiate the sum of T1 and T2, `T4 is T1 + t2, T4 =< T3`

And finally, your predicate `addUp/2` need the base case, for the empty list

```
addUp([],0).
```

And replace the last number 1 for the variable Head. You should add the first element of the list to the sum of the tail.

```
addUp([Head | Tail], Total) :-
 addUp(Tail, Total1), Total is Total1 + Head.
```

The Final program:

```
lessThanEq(List1, List2, List3) :-
    addUp(List1,T1),addUp(List2, T2), addUp(List3, T3),
    T4 is T1 + T2, T4 =< T3.

addUp([],0).
addUp([Head | Tail], Total) :-
    addUp(Tail, Total1), Total is Total1 + Head.
```